# Wordpress - return the class variables/function from shortcode function?

Tags: wordpress

How to return the class variables/function from the shortcode method?

```
class MyClass
{
    private $content;

    function MyClass()
    {
        $this->content= "value";
    }

    public function getContent()
    {
        ob_start();
        print "This is content: ". $this->content;
        $output = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        return $this->content;
    }
}
add_shortcode('architects-side', array( 'MyClass', 'getContent' )); // not work
```

The problem is that not work because I use `$this->content` in `getContent()`, what is the right way to use variables/functions in `getContent()`?

Comment: Solution given by @Felipe should work

Answer (score 1):

I didnt't test it, but I think this could work:

```
class MyClass
{
    private $content;

    function MyClass()
    {
        $this->content= "value";
        add_shortcode('architects-side', array( $this, 'getContent' ));
    }

    public function getContent()
    {
        ob_start();
        print "This is content: ". $this->content;
        $output = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        return $this->content;
    }
}
$myClass = new MyClass();
```